# How can I set my home network to access internet via remote VPN?

Tags: vpn

Here's my problem:

- I am on my home network with multiple devices (PC, Tablet, Phone, TV etc).
- I would like to have them ALL access the internet via a remote VPN, let's say, in Germany.
- I would prefer not to have to install apps on each device for the purpose.

So, is there something I can do to configure my broadband router, or by adding an additional router in the local network to achieve this?

*I wouldn't be surprised if there is an answer to this already, but I'm struggling to frame the question in a way that gets a proper answer!*

Comment: From our FAQ which you skipped; "(serverfault) is not about… Anything in a home setting"

Answer (score 0):

what type of router do you have?
get dd-wrt and under [wan connection type](http://www.dd-wrt.com/demo/index.asp), you can set it up to route your internet through a vpn.